# Lists and Matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a matrix of the form:

```
 matrix ={{a,b},{10*a,10*b}}.
```

I want to evaluate this matrix for a set of values. For example:

```
 list = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8},{9,10}},
```

where each sublist has the values of $a$ and $b$ respectively. How would I go about evaluating the matrix at the values in the list?

---

**Edit:**

More specifically, I have a list of the form:

```
OptimalPoints = {
{
 2.2575422669022256316146199310035044964832661776461`15.*^-8, 
 1.57079639622776237973336943808513436304`15.
},
{
 6.5030057578379460133211810893852417847654553996698`15.*^-8, 
 1.57079630003754406967047630250839359743`15.
},
{
 0, 
 1.57079625737764823615943901490196281871`15.
}
}
```

and the matrix is derived from the code:

```
J = 1;

Clear[ψ]
ψ[α_, χ_] := Exp[I α]*Tan[χ/2];



newcoherentstate[α_, χ_, m_] := ((ψ[α, χ])/(1 + ψ[α, χ]*
         Simplify[
          Conjugate[ψ[α, χ]], 
          Assumptions -> {Element[α, Reals], Element[χ, Reals]}
         ]))^(J) *(ψ[α, χ])^(m)*Sqrt[Binomial[2 J, J + m]];

TempNewMatrix [α_, χ_] := Simplify[
          Table[
               newcoherentstate[α, χ, m], 
               {m, J, -J, -1}
              ], 
          Assumptions -> {Element[α, Reals], Element[χ, Reals]}
        ];

NewMatrix [α_, χ_] := ArrayReshape[TempNewMatrix [α, χ], {2*J + 1, 1}];

NewMatrix1[α_, χ_] := ArrayReshape[NewMatrix[α, χ], {1, 2*J + 1}]

NewMatrixC[α_, χ_] := Simplify[
   Conjugate[NewMatrix1[α, χ]],
   Assumptions ->{Element[α, Reals], Element[χ, Reals]} 
];

NewProjector[α_, χ_] = Flatten[{NewMatrix[α, χ] .NewMatrixC[α, χ]}, 1];
```

When I run,

```
{{#1, #2}, NewProjector[α, χ]} & @@@ 
  OptimalPoints // MatrixForm
```

I don't get the desired list of matrices evaluated at points in the list `optimal points`

Comment: `matrix /. Thread[{a, b} -> #] & /@ list`.

Answer (score 1):

A clean way to do this is to define a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) and then [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) it to your list:

```
{{#1, #2}, {10 #1, 10 #2}} & @@@ list
```

> {{{1, 2}, {10, 20}}, {{3, 4}, {30, 40}}, {{5, 6}, {50, 60}}, {{7, 
>      8}, {70, 80}}, {{9, 10}, {90, 100}}}

Alternatively, you can create your own [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and Apply it to your list.

```
matrixFcn[a_, b_] := {{a, b}, {10 a, 10 b}}
matrixFcn @@@ list
```

The same output is generated.

Comment: Hey. I have been trying such methods but to no avail. I have edited the post with the relevant codes for my problem.

Comment: I believe it works if you implement it as follows `MatrixForm[#] & /@ {{#1, #2}, NewProjector[#1, #2]} & @@@ OptimalPoints`. I think you'll also want to define your `NewProjector` function with the `SetDelayed` `:=` command instead of the `Set` `=` command, although it may not appear to make a difference at this point. @junaid-aftab